# Как работает код выводящий простые числа?

Tags: javascript

Я не пойму как выполняются итерации в этом коде:

```js
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
      if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; 
    }
    console.log( i ); 
  }
```

Вот `i = 2` и `j = 2` при `i % j` должен выполниться `continue` и пропустить число `2`, но оно выводится, почему?

Объясните пожалуйста как работают в этом коде итерации, например, почему не возвращаются числа 4, 6, 8, 9, 10?

Comment: Вы не учли условие `j < i` во вложенном цикле. Когда `i == 2`, `j == 2`, условие `j < i` во вложенном цикле не выполняется, следовательно, вложенный цикл не выполнит ни одной итерации. Таким образом до проверки условия `if (i % j == 0)` при `i == 2` и `j == 2` дело не дойдёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextPrime` — [название](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) первого цикла (в современном коде такое практически не встречается), оно позволяет из вложенных циклов управлять внешним циклом.

А у вложенного:

```
for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
  if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
}
```

Написано «если хотя бы одно число `j` ДО числа `i` делится на него без остатка, значит `i` - не простое число, не надо его выводить» — вложенный цикл прерывается, а внешний (`nextPrime`) идет на следующую итерацию (`continue`).

Это можно переписать так:

```js
let n = 20;

for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  if ( !isPrime(i) ) continue;
  console.log(i);
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let j = 2; j < Math.sqrt(n + 1); j++) {
    if (n % j == 0) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

`j < Math.sqrt(n+1)` вместо `j < n`: нет смысла проверять прямо все числа, достаточно до `√n`

Comment: Спасибо большое, получается что на learn.javascript.ru (info) обучают написанию не современного кода.., где вы учили JavaScript?:)

Comment: @Dmitry Современному коду тоже учат) Как-раз на learn.javascript начал: Там просто формат хороший, каждый день прочитать одну-две статьи, что-то кодить на эту тему, за пару месяцев набежит неплохая база. А дальше, там-сям статьи / книги, и не только конкретно по JS. Одного единственного идеального источника не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, nextPrime это метка для `continue`.

```js
let n = 10;

nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; // идем на nextPrime, т. е. внутренний цикл прерывается.
   }
   console.log( i ); 
}
```

Вывод:

```
2
3
5
7
```

Резюмирую - код написан недружелюбно, но рабочий.